# GPS WOX SMS Gateway setup

Tags: clickatell

Trying to set up SMS gateway inside of GPSWOX program and it's asking for the Clickatell url - I used the "Curl" url and placed in the box.

However, when I tried to test the sms it didn't send me anything.  Does anyone know if this format is correct?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The format is nearly correct. You should use: 
`https://platform.clickatell.com/messages/http/send?apiKey=******&to=%NUMBER%&content=%MESSAGE%`

You can test it by pasting the example url in your browser (with NUMBER and MESSAGE replaced of course)